# Add extra character in URL

Tags: jmeter

I try to test simple HTTP request with below setting.
[image: Simple HTTP Request]

The response I get is:

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in user info at index 7: http://[UserName:$$MyPass@@@www.URL.com]:8080/

I know the error reason is []. As we can see in Server Name or IP is explicitly not added.

But my question is What is the reason Browser add extra [] in my URL

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't put anything but server DNS hostname or IP address into the "Server Name or IP" input field.
2. If you look into [Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) section of URL specification you will see the list of characters which cannot be present in the URL:

   > reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

   > gen-delims  = `":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"`

   > sub-delims  = `"!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="`

if your URL contains any of the above characters it needs to be escaped via [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)

3. Passing credentials in URL is not secure, I would recommend using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) instead, check out [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) for details.
4. If you are uncertain regarding how to simulate this or that browser call in JMeter - just record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)